# Vuejs: data through the router-view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it a good practice to pass data through the router-view? I have a nested router and some children have to have access to the data that parent is having. I know Vuex is the way to pass the data all over the app, but I`d like to know what are the exact disadvantages of binding data to the router-view to make it available in the child components.
So for now I have something like that:

```
<router-view v-bind:list="array" />
```

Comment: are you able to pass data from parent to child ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to the rendered component using the `router-view` but most likely is not what you want.

Routing can happen from any part of your app, but if you pass info via `router-view` you need to update the data that is bound to the view, which in turn means to have access to the component enclosing the template that presents `router-view`. This ends up tightly coupling components or using the bus/vuex.

You could use `Vuex` to pass the information, but there is a much easier way to pass information when routing.

You can define your route to transform parameters set when routing to props to the component. More info [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components). This means that you can make a call similar to this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'routeName', params: { id: 1 }}">Go to route</router-link>
```

and then whatever component is registered for `routeName` will get the prop `id` set to value `1`. The same will happen if you trigger a navigation programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can programtically pass through router like below
 from parent component trigger below fn on click or redirection

```
this.$router.push({
      name: 'ChildRouteName',
      params: {'type':'name', 'id': '1',}
})
```

and in child  component receive the parameters like this

```
type = this.$route.params['type']
id = this.$route.params['id']
```